# Sass with webpack not working

Tags: sass, webpack, postcss

I'm building an app using webpack, react, babel, and Sass. I've been trying to get Sass working, but it's not playing ball. It's not throwing any errors, it just doesn't seem to be compiling properly, and when I examine the element in Dev Tools, it simply says "invalid property value" where I've referenced a variable. Is there something glaringly obvious I'm doing wrong?

[image: My file structure]

My app.scss:

```
@import '../../../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css';
@import '../variables.scss';

/*
 * Base styles
 * ========================================================================== */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    color: $blue;
}
```

My variables.scss:

```
/*
 * Colors
 * ========================================================================== */

$blue: #334c6a;
$yellow: #f6d463;
$white: #ffffff;
$black: #000000;

/*
 * Typography
 * ========================================================================== */

$font-family-base:      'Segoe UI', 'HelveticaNeue-Light', sans-serif;

/*
 * Layout
 * ========================================================================== */

$container-margin: 55px;
```

Webpack.config:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var precss = require('precss');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build/',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.png', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        context: __dirname,
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer
        ]
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
      rules: [
     {
       test: /\.jsx?$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
     },
     {
       test: /\.scss$/,
       loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
     },
     {
       test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
       loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
     },
     {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
     }
   ]
  }
};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "postcss": "^5.2.17",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone knows wich one is the icon theme of the print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This config is working with webpack 2 and sass.

```
    {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']          
    },
```

And then in the App.js file

```
import './app.scss'
```

The complete webpack.config

```js
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var precss = require('precss');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
   './index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), not needed any more
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        context: __dirname,
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer
        ]
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' , 'postcss-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect - is there a reason the current webpack.config would be screwing things up?

Comment: the 'postcss-loader' doesn't transform the scss files. There for you need the sass-loader.

Comment: This worked once I ran "npm install sass-loader --save-dev" then "npm install --save-dev node-sass" - thanks!